# Python Selenium Wait for User Interaction to Continue

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a python script that basically goes on a page and automatically submits fields for me.

But there are some cases that I might have to interfere and do some manual changes but I don't want to make the program `sleep()` for let's say 5mins in case the user has to interfere because in case there is no need for the user to interfere he/she will just stand there and wait for 5 mins :/

So basically what I want is for selenium to wait for the user to press a button with an XPATH of lets say `XPATH1` before it proceeds with the rest of the code,
I could also do the same with a Key combination, what I mean by that is when the user checks that everything is ok he could press `ENTER` and that would trigger selenium to continue

```
# Pseudo code
waitForUsr= WebDriverWait.until(User_click_Button_with_XPATH("XPATH"))
waitForUsr= WebDriverWait.until(Keys.ENTER_is_pressed)
```

Thank you for your time!
I hope you can help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use wait until for an object/element appears in the page after submiting.
OR in most websites the submit button disappears/greyed out when clicked. In such pages we can wait for the button to disappear.

This code will help if the submit button disappears once clicked.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 300).until(EC.invisibility_of_element((By.XPATH, XPATH1)))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but unfortunately the button does not disappear,
Is it possible to do that when on the event that the button is pressed ?

Comment: Is there any change in the browser when the button is pressed?

Comment: Yes a new <backdrop> and <window> are generated when I press the button that has are always the same ( I tried trice to copy it and it was)
Can I somehow trigger the code to continue when it appears? They don't have a Name or ID tag but I hope it is possible with an XPATH

Comment: In that case you can use -  `WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))`

Comment: Yes but it crashed after 10 seconds so I thought of this
```
def theFunc():
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"XPATH")))
    except:
        theFunc()
```
This just keeps calling itself until that event occurs and it continues
It works so I am happy, thank you for the help mate, have a good one !